# PHP file_get_contents different behaviour for the same domain

Tags: php

I've a probably really silly question about **file_get_contents**, I want to retrieve content on a website and this works properly when I serve to the below code:

```
$file = file_get_contents( $dataSourceURL, false, $context );
```

$dataSourceURL = 'http://somedomain.com', but when I'm serving a specific page of this website like $dataSourceURL = 'http://somedomain.com/c-4-hookah-coals-hookah-charcoal.html' it returns nothing.

Does anybody know something about this issue?

**UPDATE**

I know we can pass GET params using the below code:

```
            $getdata = http_build_query(
                array(
                    'var1' => 'some content',
                    'var2' => 'doh'
                )
            );

            $opts = array('http' =>
                array(
                    'method'  => 'GET',
                    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'content' => $getdata
                )
            );

            $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
```

but than... is there a simple way to resolve this kind of url query 'c-4-hookah-coals-hookah-charcoal.html' ?

Comment: if you simply want to read the content you can pass only URL $file = file_get_contents( $dataSourceURL) no need for any other parameters

Comment: if you want to pass some headers then try this page examples http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Yes, but how to pass simply GET parameters when they are rewritten via .htaccess is there an 'out of the box' solution for this one ?

Comment: you are trying on http://somedomain.com you can try with other site i have tested this is working

Comment: no, that was an example. To be more specific I wanted to use: hookah-shisha.com - that is not a secret in here, but it's not relevant also.

Comment: I've tried, and the domain is not the problem. The problem is how to pass a rewritten GET query to the file_get_contents function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_contents` works like unix `wget`, so you can try simply:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://www.hookah-shisha.com/c-4-hookah-coals-hookah-charcoal.html');
```